# C# unclear symbols from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, decode

I have an alcohol tester with serial port interface, here is my source part

```
    tester.Parity = Parity.None;
    tester.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    tester.DataBits = 8;
    tester.BaudRate = 9600;
    tester.PortName = "COM3";
    tester.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(tester_DataReceived);
    {
        tester.Open();
    }

    void tester_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {            
        string s = tester.ReadExisting();
    }
```

but the string s in debug mode contains unclear symbols --> "`??`???ff??",
if i write that string to a file and open the file it contains this data

```
    663f 3f3f 603f 663f 3f3f 6066 3f3f 3f60
    3f66 3f3f 603f 1e3f 3f60 3f66 3f3f 6066
    3f3f 3f60 3f66 3f3f 3f60 663f 3f3f 603f
    663f 3f60 663f 3f3f 603f 067e 3f60 663f
    3f3f 603f 663f 3f3f 6066 3f3f 3f60 3f66
    1e3f 6066 3f3f 3f60 3f06 7e3f 6066 3f3f
    3f60 3f66 3f3f 3f60 3f1e 3f3f 603f 663f
    3f60 663f 3f3f 603f 067e 3f60 663f 3f3f
    603f 663f 3f3f 6066 3f3f 3f60 3f66 3f3f
```

There is an app written with WinForms. That app recieves from that tester simple english words defining tester state for example - wait, end, result.
My goal is to write this function using WPF. How can i actually decode that string? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to read the data from the port as soon as it is received? In this case you may read incomplete data. e.g. a string is being written to your serial port e.g. i am coming. But your code will read as "i" then "a" and so on.

Comment: Just gonna throw this out there: It's probably not a string. It's no doubt a stream of bytes.

Comment: are you sure about the baud rate ?

Comment: the problem is that you may read garbage from serail port. You need to filter that out according to your needs.

Comment: Ehsan Ullah, no, this is not garbage, i have receive data from the device but data was similar

Comment: KbManu, you are my hero :) i set baud rate to 4800 and everything is fine :) Received data -> $WAIT\r\n$WAIT\r\n$WAIT\r\n$WAIT\r\n$STANBY\r\n

Comment: Good ! Have a nice time !

Comment: If it worked, then, you can acknowledge the comment !?